# sort nested struct single linked and double

Tags: c++, c, xcode, visual-c++, gcc

I have nested as:

```
typedef struct a{
    const char *        LongName;
    const char *        ShortName;
    int                 a;
    struct a    *       next;
}Level5;

typedef struct a1{
    const char *        LongName;
    const char *        ShortName;
    int                 frequency5;
    int                 id;
    Level5  *           linked;
    struct a1*          next_a1;
}Level4;

typedef struct a2{
    const char      *   Name;
    int                 frequency4;
    Level4      *       linked;
    int                 id;
    struct a2   *       next;
}Level3;

typedef struct a3{
    const char *        LongName;
    const char *        ShortName;
    int                 frequency3
    int                 id;
    Level3      *       linked;
}Level2;

typedef struct a4{
    const char *        LongName;
    const char *        ShortName;
    _Bool           top;
    int             id;
    int             frequency2;
    Level2      *   lined;
}Level1;


typedef struct cat{
    int         id;
const char  *   CatName;
Level1      *   linked;
}CAT;

CAT     total[256];
```

Now I want to sort the Linked nested structures structure as under:

```
 1. Level 5 -> LongName

 2. Level 4 -> ShortName

 3. Level 3 -> Name

 4. Level 2 -> Frequency3

               Level 1
                   |
                   | Level 2
     ====================================================
     | Level3         |Level3         |level 3
 =============       
 |     next       next   
level4 ->     lev4 ->   lev4
 |              |
 |                   =====================================
===============================       |    
|       next        next           Level5 ->  level5  ->  level5
Level5  ->    Level5  ->  level5
```

Comment: Need clarification:  Are all items sorted by level first, then by specialty?

Comment: Are all level 5 items sorted by `LongName` even though they share common fields?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews First question answer is yes that is what I looking for. LongName is different in every structure. For install level5 abc then level4 def level3 ghi level2 jkl level1 xzy. Names may be same but values are different in each structure

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the following data structure:

```
Level5 node --> Level5 node --> Level5 node  
  |  
  v  
Level4 node --> Level4 node --> Level4 node  
  |  
  v  
Level3 node --> level3 node --> Level3 node  
  |  
  v  
Level2 node --> level2 node --> Level2 node
```

If this is the case, your data structure can be simplified:

```
struct Node
{
};

struct Node_Row
{
   unsigned int level;
   std::list<Node> nodes_in_row;
};

struct data_structure
{
   std::list<Node_Row> levels;
};
```

You should have one comparator function that sorts the rows and another that sorts the levels.

Also, since you tagged your question as C++, you should save yourself some troubles and use `std::string` instead of `char *`.  The `std::string` manages dynamic memory allocation and deallocation for you, whereas `char *` you have manage memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: I have done some ascii art work to show the structures for better understanding